# SSRS Create As Many Tables As Needed (Using One Dataset) Based on a DataSet Field

Tags: reporting-services

I have a query that returns relevant data about inspectors and how long it takes them to respond to issues. The only parameters are a BeginDate and EndDate so for any given date range there could be anywhere from 0 to 100 inspectors.

I am using only one dataset and it contains an "Inspector" field that I'm hoping can be used as a filter to create as many tables as there are inspectors.

*I know you can set filters on tables but from my (limited) SSRS knowledge, you must already have the tables created and the filters are typically hard-coded.* **What I need, is some way for the report to see how many Inspectors there are in the dataset and group those records into their own tables, repeating the same one created tablix over and over as needed.**

This is being done strictly in SSRS 2012, not using a ReportViewer where back-end code could help me out unfortunately...

I don't have any code examples to provide, like I said I know you can do filtering but I am at a loss when it comes to doing something like this dynamically based on data... Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the report design you could either...

**Single report with grouping**

```
1. Create a single tablix.
2. Create a row group by Inspector and then add whatever fields you need to the details section. 
3. You can optionally set page breaks between instances of your Inspector rowgroup from the rowgroup properties.
```

**Sub report method**

```
1. Create a subreport that accepts a parameter (InspectorID for example).
2. In the subreport filter the dataset using the parameter passed in so it only return data for a single inspector.
3. Add whatever controls you need to the report to handle a single Inspector
4. Create a main report 
5. Add a dataset that gives you a simple distinct list of Inspectors, this will be used to pass parameters to the subreport.  
    Lets assume it just contains a list of InspectorIDs.
6. Add a list control to the report and set it's dataset property to the dataset that contains your list of InspectorIDs
7. Right-click in the list control's 'cell' and insert a subreport. 
8. Set the subreport property to the subreport you created earlier and    set that parmameter IsnpectorID to your InpsectorID field.
```

This will produce a subreport for each instance of inspector it finds.

Sorry about the format of this answer, in a rush!

Comment: Worked great, thanks so much! I need to get used to remembering that the pagebreak property belongs to many different things and can be used in very creative ways!