# How can I repeat an SSRS design on consecutive pages by date?

Tags: date, matrix, reporting-services, parameters, page-break

Frequently, I am required to design SSRS reports that include 4 or 5 small, related matrices and display them on separate pages by date according to the user-selected date range - usually the previous work week.

I need the same matrices to run on each new page with results for the next date in the range.

Is there a way to do this efficiently?

Now, I design one set of matrices, setting a page break after the last of them, copying and pasting them down the body of the report until there are five sets - one set per weekday.

(I have set parameters for setting the date range @BeginDate and @EndDate with defaults for previous Monday and previous Friday.)

Then, I set filters on all of the matrices by an expression to get the desired date.

The clicking and dragging should be easy but getting them in the exact, desired places has caused all sorts of frustration.

I'm a seasoned user of SSRS, and I really think I may be missing something.  There must be an easier way.

Comment: Use sub reports. You basically create a single copy of your design with your 5 matrices that accepts a single date as a parameter. Then you create a 'master' report that has a dataset containing a list of dates (this is what the user will see and select as per your current report). Then add a table to this report that produces one row per date selected, in this table insert your subreport and pass in the data value. You will end up with your subreport repeated for each day. If you want to see an example, let me know and I'll knock something up.

Comment: That sounds much more practical.  I'll try that today and let you know how it goes.  Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at the SubReport option in this answer. It's not a full walk-thru but gives a bit more detail than I can fit in a comment.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212190

Comment: This has worked for me.  Hooray!

Comment: Thanks also for suggesting stackoverflow.com/questions/53212190

Comment: No problem. If you found the other answer useful you can vote it up.

Comment: I apologize for asking this, but I searched the Help Center and couldn't find out.  (I'm new to Stack Overflow.)My screen in Stack overflow is not showing any large arrows of check marks beside the comments.

Comment: No problem. I don't mean on this question (as there is no answer posted) but on the question I linked to. On the answer I posted you should be able to see 2 round buttons with up and down arrows (triangles actually). You can use those to vote up and answer even if it's already been accepted. If you can't find it, don't worry, it might be that you don't have suffiencient reputation yet.

Comment: I think you need 15 reputation before you can vote. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399

Comment: Thanks so much, Alan!  You have saved me so much frustration. Plus, I am expecting to be assigned similar reports in the future, and this technique should work for them also.